# Java binary tree postorder traversal recursively

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree, tree-traversal, postorder

//   Trying to return a list containing the values in 'a' by traversing  the nodes in postorder. In Junit it says that "String cannot be cast to List". Help please.

```
public static List postorder(Tree a) {
        if (a.getEmpty()) 
            return List.empty(); 
        else
              postorder(a.getLeft());
              postorder(a.getRight());

              return ListOps.append(postorder(a.getLeft()), 
                        List.cons(a.getValue(), postorder(a.getRight())));
            }
```

Comment: Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
And at least add your exception

Comment: Give us a hint about your problem.  What makes you think that something is indeed wrong with your code?

Comment: What does `ListOps.append(...)` return?  From your error, I'd make a strong guess it returns a `String`, while your method returns a `List`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is here: `ListOps.append(..` 
I say probably because your question is totally unclear, so I think that `ListOps` is a `String`, but your method return `List`...

So use a `ArrayList` or another class that implement `List`, and add the elements into it...

Comment: No I ran into other problems and had to move on, thank you for asking.